# WDIO is not entering value in password text wrap field[React native web]

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

We are automating a react native web application on mobile web browser using WebdriverIO,Appium,mocha framework
while we navigate the URL, signIN page will open to login for the user

script able to enter user text on userName field but password value not entering the value in password field , we can able click on this but text not entering
Source:[image]

Code:
$('#LogInModel_UserName').waitForExist();

$('#LogInModel_UserName').addValue("mytesting@gmail.com");

$('#login-password').waitForExist();

$('#login-password').addValue("passme"); // here its the entering blank instead of "passme"

Can someone share some solution ,how can i enter password value in password field?

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from looking at your screenshot and code snippet, I believe the issue is that you are targeting the wrong element.

You want to target the id on the password input field which is `#LogInModel_Password`.

So your code would be:

```
$('#LogInModel_UserName').waitForExist();
$('#LogInModel_UserName').addValue("mytesting@gmail.com");
$('#LogInModel_Password').waitForExist();
$('#LogInModel_Password').addValue("passme")
```

This should fix your issue since it looks like you are already targeting the username field correctly and it works.